# Express number of ways integer can be written as coefficient in generating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Question:
"Express the number of ways that an integer $n$ can be written as a sum of a cube of an integer $s\ge-1$ plus the fourth power of an integer $t$ plus the square of an odd integer $r$ as a certain coefficient in an appropriate generating series."

So trying to simplify this convoluted question I arrive at:

Express the number of ways that an integer $n$ can be written as a sum of $s^3+t^4+r^2$ where$ -1\lt s \lt Z,t\in Z,r\in Zodd$ as a certain coefficient in an appropriate generating series.  (where $Z$ is all integers).

So I believe that the sum would be something similar to

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(s^3+t^4+r^2)\ . $$

I think that what it's asking me to do after this is determine the coefficient $c_n$ so that it is the number of combinations of $s,j,r$ so that  $(s^3+t^4+r^2) = n$. I'm not sure how to go about this, if I'm even on the right track, or how the constraints on $s,j,r$ would come into play.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the coefficient of $x^n$ in 
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{i^3} \sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{j^4} \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{(2k+1)^2}$$
you will see that it will be exactly the number of ways to write $n$ in the specified way. This is what "they" want, I am pretty sure.

Comment: This works, thanks.  Could you possibly expand a little bit on how you arrived at this generating series?

Comment: This is a standard way to deal with partition-type problems, and goes back to Euler (a standard application is the question of "how many ways can you make change for a dollar if you have the usual american change  -- in that case, the generating function will be _rational_, so you can express the general term in closed form, which I don't think you can for your problem).